# What is the way to creating and using custom Attribute for already existing tags in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I want to use custom tag in html for example,
in input field i want data from database so is there any way to use custom tag , which will dynamically load data in input field after loading the html(jsp,asp etc. langugae) page?

I want some thing tag like this

```
<input type='text' name='city' table='location' column='city'>
```

is this possible? 
I learn that we can use **getAttribute()** function but can it bring data from database?

if yes then Could you tell me how to do this in **JSP**

Comment: I think you mean using custom *attributes* on standard tags. If this is so, please edit the title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JSP code is executed before JavaScript code.

The most ideal way to achieve this is to create a custom tag library.

> JSP technology provides a mechanism for encapsulating other types of dynamic functionality in [custom tags](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html), which are extensions to the JSP language. Some examples of tasks that can be performed by custom tags include operating on implicit objects, processing forms, accessing databases and other enterprise services such as email and directories, and implementing flow control.
>
> Custom tag library consists of one or more Java classes called Tag Handlers and an XML tag library descriptor file (tag library).

That way you can simply use the custom tag to get the data from the database and display the result in the `value` attribute of the `<input>` tag.

Your code for fetching data from the database will be in one of the class in your tag library.

Your JSP code would look like this

```
<%@taglib prefix="db" uri="/WEB-INF/database.tld"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Custom Tag example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='text' name='city' value='<db:substring table="location" column="city"/>' />
    </body>
</html>
```

You will need to create at least one Java class and an XML tag library descriptor file (tag library).

---

[Tutorial: Create JSP custom tag library](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-create-custom-tag-library-taglib-in-jsp/)

Comment: @Mohsin Chaudhari hope it solves your question. Use the [Java EE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalj.html) for understanding custom tags in more details.